# Out of String Space - <Out of Memory> Errors

Tags: variables, vb6, out-of-memory

I have a complex code, but summarizing, I have this:

A `RecordSet` named `rstRecords`;
Global `string` variable named `StrLetters`;
A `string` variable named `StrText` that has a `different` content for each time it runs the `loop`;
A `While Loop`.

Everytime the `loop` goes to the `next`, it `Add more content to the string StrLetters`. Like:

```
Do While Not rstRecords.EOF
   'Codes Here
    Here I call a method named FeedLetter, that has lot of codes but also feed this string
Loop

Private Sub FeedLetter()

   'Lot of code
   'And Here I feed that string

   StrLetters = StrLetters + StrText

End Sub
```

When it has a lot of records, and you place your mouse over the variable `StrLetters` it shows this tooltip `<Out Of Memory>`. And the following error, `String Out of Space`.

When The `loop`is over, a method will use the value of the `StrLetters` and print if on a paper.

I know that it's fired because in `VB6` the variables have a `Max Lengh Value`.
I'd just like to know a way to work around this...

**UPDATE**

Here is where the error is happening (Method of `cStringBuilderClass` given by Dave).

I call:

```
Buffer.CapacityIncrement = Len(strIncommingContent)
Buffer.Append (strIncommingContent)
```

The error happens here:

```
    Public Sub EnsureCapacity(ByVal lngMinimum As Long)
Dim lngDiff As Long
   If ((m_lngCapacity < lngMinimum) And (lngMinimum > 0)) Then
      ' If current capacity isn't enough, then figure out how many capacity increments you need to meet
      ' the given minimum
      lngDiff = lngMinimum - m_lngCapacity
      If (lngDiff < m_lngCapacityIncrement) Then
         ' The If...ElseIf... is quicker than the math in the ElseIf
         lngDiff = m_lngCapacityIncrement
      ElseIf (lngDiff > m_lngCapacityIncrement) Then
         ' Note that the division is using \ operator instead of /.  \ truncates decimal part
         lngDiff = ((lngDiff \ m_lngCapacityIncrement) + 1) * m_lngCapacityIncrement
      End If
      m_str = m_str & String$(lngDiff, vbNullChar)
      m_lngCapacity = (m_lngCapacity + lngDiff)
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is probably just a limitation of the debugger and what it can display, and not actually an issue with the code.

Comment: @KenWhite My problem isn't with the fact that it shows the `<Out of Memory>`. I just need an Idea of how to work around with this limitation. Or how may I test if the string is already Full, then I could just create another.

Comment: Your question says "..you place your mouse over the variable", which can only happen when debugging the code. The "<Out of Memory>" tooltip is from the debugger, and as I said is probably just a limitation of what the debugger allows for visualizing the content of variables. If it can only show a certain amount of data in the tooltip, there's no way to "work around" the limitation. You could always add a numeric variable and track the actual length of `StrLetters` in it, and then watch that numeric variable instead.

Comment: How do you declare `StrLetters`? Do you put a limit or is it like this `Dim StrLetters as String`? If you do it this way, the string should be able to accommodate up to 2GB of data. Are you assigning more to it then that?

Comment: I would avoid that string concatenation (`StrLetters = StrLetters + StrText`) like the plague because of the extremely poor performance it will come with.  And it is probably also the reason for your out-of-memory error.  Each string concatenation results in a new block of memory to be allocated for the resulting string to be put into.  So for a moment you are using more than double the memory as both the old and new string is in memory.  Use a StringBuilder class like the one described [here].(http://www.vbaccelerator.com/home/VB/Code/Techniques/StringBuilder/article.asp)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try. @DaveMichener ! But I can't create stringBuilder, do I need a component ?

Comment: @George I declare it like you describled... Without setting a fixed limit.

Comment: That page has a download link with a sample StringBuilder class.  Just add that class to your solution and use `MyStringBuilder.Append(StrText)` instead of `StrLetters = StrLetters + StrText`.  At the end of your `Do While ...` loop you can say `StrLetters = MyStringBuilder.ToString()`

Comment: @DaveMichener Thanks !! But , If i write the `StrLetters = MyStringBuilder.ToString()`. the `StrLetters` wont overflow again ?

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro - Are your strings really over 2GB long? Then you should use arrays of strings or string builder like Dave mentioned and dont assign it to a string. That being said, if your strings go above 2GB in size, you should really re-evaluate the logic of your code. I don't know what specific task the code does, but in most cases you can break down the task into smaller pieces and work on those small pieces instead.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, VB6 supports about 2 billion characters [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262664(v=vs.60).aspx).  So only if your loop attempts to create something larger than that will you get into trouble.  The out-of-memory error can happen with strings that are smaller if you have multiple copies of those strings. By using a StringBuilder class you use the memory more efficiently and hopefully avoid the out-of-memory altogether.

Comment: @George  It's not my code, it's a software builded a looong time ago, i'm just fixing some issues that appear in the way, you know ? Its all messed up u.u. I'm trying to use the StringBuilder The task of this variable is to be used in a Print...

Comment: @DaveMichener With: `MyStringBuilder.Append(StrText)`, an error ocurred ... `"An Instruction on "0x7c911d8f" made reference to memory in "0xffffff8".The memory couldn't be "read".`

Comment: Updated my question explaning the error, check it out when posible, Thanks @DaveMichener

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro did the `Append` method ever work, or did this error occur on the first loop?

Comment: @DaveMichener It happens in the first loop.

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro I created a test app and it worked Ok. I created my own StringBuffer class ~10 years ago from an article I read by Francesco Balena, a VB6 wizard. That class did not use any Win API calls to do it's work and has been flawless in the commercial app that it has been used in ever since. I will post back when I find something to share.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to find a link to that very old Visual Basic Programmers Journal article that I was referring to.  I will just post the code that I created based on that article and has been working well for many years now.

One of the things I really like about this implementation is that it lets you set an initial size to the buffer.  The slowest part of any StringBuilder/StringBuffer class in any language (that has immutable strings like VB6, VB.Net, C#, Java, etc.) is when it has to resize itself to fit the newly appended or inserted text.  If you can make a good guess as to how big the final string will be, you can call the `EnsureCapacity` method before starting (or at anytime really) to make the buffer the appropriate size in one call instead.

In your case, if you can find out how many rows are in your `RecordSet` and multiply that by the average size string that is to be added, you will get a good rough estimate of the final string size. Use that value on the call to `EnsureCapacity`.  You can also set the increment size that will be used when the buffer has to be expanded.  In my code the buffer increases in 64 character chunks.  If you know, for example, that each `Append` operation is going to be ~1500 characters, then set `CapacityIncrement` property to at least 1500 as that will be a littler quicker.  I would still advise to use the final string size approach I described.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_str As String
Private m_lngLength As Long             ' Current length (char count)
Private m_lngCapacity As Long           ' Current capacity (length of buffer)
Private m_lngCapacityIncrement As Long  ' Number of characters to add when incrementing capacity

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
   m_lngCapacityIncrement = 64
End Sub

Public Sub Append(ByVal str As String)
Dim lngLen As Long
   lngLen = Len(str)
   If lngLen = 0 Then Exit Sub
   EnsureCapacity (m_lngLength + lngLen)
   Mid$(m_str, m_lngLength + 1, lngLen) = str
   m_lngLength = m_lngLength + lngLen
End Sub

Public Property Get Capacity() As Long
   Capacity = m_lngCapacity
End Property

Public Property Get CapacityIncrement() As Long
   CapacityIncrement = m_lngCapacityIncrement
End Property

Public Property Let CapacityIncrement(ByVal lngNewValue As Long)
   If lngNewValue > 0 Then m_lngCapacityIncrement = lngNewValue
End Property

Public Sub EnsureCapacity(ByVal lngMinimum As Long)
Dim lngDiff As Long
   If ((m_lngCapacity < lngMinimum) And (lngMinimum > 0)) Then
      ' If current capacity isn't enough, then figure out how many capacity increments you need to meet
      ' the given minimum
      lngDiff = lngMinimum - m_lngCapacity
      If (lngDiff < m_lngCapacityIncrement) Then
         ' The If...ElseIf... is quicker than the math in the ElseIf
         lngDiff = m_lngCapacityIncrement
      ElseIf (lngDiff > m_lngCapacityIncrement) Then
         ' Note that the division is using \ operator instead of /.  \ truncates decimal part
         lngDiff = ((lngDiff \ m_lngCapacityIncrement) + 1) * m_lngCapacityIncrement
      End If
      m_str = m_str & String$(lngDiff, vbNullChar)
      m_lngCapacity = (m_lngCapacity + lngDiff)
   End If
End Sub

Public Property Get Length() As Long
   Length = m_lngLength
End Property

Public Function GetString() As String
   GetString = left$(m_str, m_lngLength)
End Function

Public Sub Reset()
   m_str = ""
   m_lngLength = 0
   m_lngCapacity = 0
   m_lngCapacityIncrement = 64
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks Perfect !! But, how may I do the `Buffer.ToString` ?

Comment: Use `StrLetters = Buffer.GetString()`

Comment: On the method EnsureCapacity, the String out of Space ocurred in this line -> `m_str = m_str & String$(lngDiff, vbNullChar)`

Comment: What was the value of lngDiff?

Comment: Now, it's no longer happening in the first time of the loop... The error happens in the `m_str = m_str & String$(lngDiff, vbNullChar)`. `lngDiff = 259974`

Comment: Can you tell me what the following have for values? `len(m_str)`, `m_lngLength`, `m_lngCapacity` and `m_lngCapacityIncrement`? Also, what about `Err.Number`?